# What's a word for when someone doesn't hold a belief close enough?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to make a point about if you don't believe in something strong enough, you lose that belief.

Comment: I call that "superstition."

Answer (score 3):

The way "**half-hearted**" is commonly used could apply, although it is more commonly used to describe efforts than beliefs themselves. "**half-heartedly**" would be the adverb.

Perhaps: *"His half-hearted belief in religion left him with neither the solace of faith nor sufficient confidence that his destiny was in his own hands."*

Basically, as you will see in the example sentences from the Oxford dictionary below, "half-hearted" is used not only to suggest lack of commitment or enthusiasm, but also failing to achieve what is half-heartedly pursued.

> [***half-hearted*** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/half-hearted)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Without enthusiasm or energy.
>
> ‘a half-hearted attempt’
>
> *‘After a half-hearted effort at saving my pocket money, I quickly emptied my account.’*
>
> *‘We attempted a team cheer, but the effort was half-hearted and just embarrassing.’*
>
> *‘It was a half-hearted attempt to draw level and one which referee Colin Hardie rightfully ignored.’*
>
> *‘The half-hearted attempt to clean up with dustpan and brush did little more than reposition them.’*
>
> *‘I make a half-hearted attempt to clean my room but end up surfing the internet aimlessly.’*

Answer (score 0):

Although the words and examples in my answer have a rather religious context, they could be used in non-religious situations as well, because the emphasis is not on religion as such, but on **insufficient belief.**

(1)The word **lukewarm** has been used to describe insufficient belief, as you can see from this Google search for *lukewarm belief*

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=lukewarm+belief&oq=lukewarm+belief&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.6320j1j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Random examples:

> His faith was at best **lukewarm**, and hence failed to survive the severe stress of his wife's sudden and senseless demise.
>
> 'People whose belief is **lukewarm** are likely to lose it altogether in the face of extreme adversity,' the preacher said.
>
> Their faith in the teacher's disciplinary capabilities was only **lukewarm**, and the incident of the *small boys and the inkpot* led to her summary dismissal.
>
> The old lady asserted that a **lukewarm** faith in the Lord was by no means a sure ticket to the Kingdom of Heaven.

(2) You could also consider the numerous examples from religious books where somebody is said to have *'believed, but not enough'* in the god(s) - **Moses** is the most famous example:

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=moses+did+not+believe+enough&oq=moses&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j69i59j69i60j5j69i60.2161j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

You can easily find other names, and they are probably found in all religions. Such names *have become a sort of shorthand* for a lack of enough belief, which apparently *'cost them the fullness of divine grace.*'

There are even expressions like 'don't be Moses' / 'don't be a Moses', which can be used to refer to lack of enough faith in God / self / somebody / something (as in the following examples which are articles written by bloggers)

http://winners-family.com/dont-be-moses/

http://dawnvilledollardays.blogspot.in/2014/09/dont-be-moses.html?m=0